# Include module html files created with sphinx.ext.viewcode in Search index

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm using the sphinx.ext.viewcode extension to build links to source code in particular project. It works very well, and creates a source code html file for each module referenced in the rst sources. However, these module html files are not included in the Sphinx search index.

I can do a literalinclude directive at the bottom of each module doc page and make the source code searchable, but that way I loose the links to the source that the sphinx.ext.viewcode extension provide, unless I use both literalinclude and sphinx.ext.viewcode. So is there a way to make the source code html files created by sphinx.ext.viewcode be included in the search index?